# SignalR with Windows Authentication not working when published to IIS

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a Blazor Server Chat app which uses a SignalR hub to push messages to the client.  The Authentication being used is Windows Auth.

The messages do not make it to an individual user. I have tested broadcasting, which does indeed work to send the message over SignalR, but of course to everyone.

The issue is with the name of the User that is registered with SignalR.  Each user is supposed to have an individual name, and for Windows Auth, the guidance is to implement a [NameUserIdProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0#windows-authentication) like this:

public class NameUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
{
return connection.User?.Identity?.Name;
}
}

The issue however, is that this does not return the current windows user, it returns the user account that the website runs under which of course is the same for all user.

I have tried adding a customer claim to the ClaimsTransformer, but it appears this claim is not available at the time of the connecting.

I don't see how to resolve this. Any advice would be appreciated.